# Unable to acess site on port 80 via apache2?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I have installed CMS and using the following configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
 ServerAdmin admin@example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/chamilo
 ServerName 127.0.0.1

 <Directory /var/www/html/chamilo/>
      Options FollowSymlinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also tried different configurations

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

I have given Servername 127.0.0.1, localhost, 0.0.0.0 but none of them seems accessible.

Any help is appreciated... Thanks

Comment: This is a question for https://serverfault.com You will find more people willing and able to help there.

Answer (score 1):

[Allow Port 80 Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b98W4.png)

Add a rule to the security group of the instance allowing PORT 80 on 0.0.0.0/0 CIDR Block and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reviewing port 80 in your security groups and simply running curl.

> curl http://localhost